# Нужна помощь с анимацией в MAUI

Tags: c#, android, .net, xaml, maui

У меня почему то не хочет выполнятся анимация, все показывает на экране правильно, но анимация не работает,код писался для андроид, что делать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код c#

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace Hello
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Attach the event handler for the animation
            Appearing += OnPageAppearing;
        }

        private async void OnPageAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double centerX = 0.8;
            double centerY = 0.825;
            double radius = 0.5; // Adjust the radius as needed

            while (true)
            {
                // Move in a circular path
                for (double angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 1)
                {
                    double radians = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
                    double x = centerX + radius * Math.Cos(radians);
                    double y = centerY + radius * Math.Sin(radians);

                    await MurImage.TranslateTo(x, y, 5000); // 16 milliseconds for smoother animation
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

код хамл

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Hello.MainPage"           
             BackgroundColor="#000000">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Label Text="My PD" FontSize="20" TextColor="#FFFFFF"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="170, 110, 100, 80" />
        <Label Text="Bill Customer" FontSize="15" TextColor="#FFFFFF"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="72, 45, 200, 80" />
        <Label Text="bill-c@energipays.com" FontSize="10" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="72, 70, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="16" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="160, 180, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="16" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="220, 180, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="17" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="190, 713, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="17" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="67, 348, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="17" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="84, 610, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Label Text="N/A" FontSize="17" TextColor="#707070"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="294, 610, 200, 80" FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        <Image Source="ellipse.png" 
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.035, 0.039, 50, 80" 
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="bolt.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.8, 0.053, 32, 60" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="menu.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.94, 0.052, 34, 60" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="settings.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95, 0.12, 40, 80" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="err.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.64, 0.13, 28, 64" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="box.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.72, 0.13, 28, 64" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="modem.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.27, 0.13, 20, 65" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="wifi.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.182, 0.13, 20, 65" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="dol.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.35, 0.13, 34, 65" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="rec9.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.8, 150, 100" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="rec8.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.82, 200, 150" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="palka.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.326, 0.41, 100, 150" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="rec6.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.61, 0.41, 100, 150" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="rocket.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.63, 0.93, 22, 60" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="smart.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.65, 235, 300" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="off.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.835, 0.55, 58, 70" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="rule.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.835, 0.64, 54, 70" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="mon.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.18, 0.42, 34, 65" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="socket.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.22, 0.785, 34, 65" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="drop.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.93, 41, 65" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="chart.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.23, 0.55, 23, 50" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="battery.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.38, 0.93, 22, 60" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="adres.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.21, 0.64, 53, 70" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="e9.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.582, 0.325, 10, 10" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="e10.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.443, 0.325, 10, 10" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="e12.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.862, 10, 10" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="e13.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.69, 0.765, 10, 10" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="e14.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.31, 0.765, 10, 10" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="grid.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.44, 0.29, 20, 60" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="tower.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.26, 45, 60" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="peak.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.59, 0.29, 45, 68" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="heating.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.773, 0.785, 30, 68" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <Image Source="e11.png" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.27, 0.425, 10, 10" 
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        <BoxView Color="#00FF00" x:Name="MurImage"
                 WidthRequest="30"
                 HeightRequest="3"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.4, 0.4235, 10, 10" 
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"/>

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Метод то хоть запускается? Точку останова ставили?

Comment: Почему вы не приняли ответ на один из прошлых вопросов и никак на него не отреагировали? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1564028/373567

Comment: так я задал новый, уже с кодом с#

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на ответ, перечитайте тот вопрос, прочитайте ответ. Примите его или напишите в комментариях, почему ответ неправильный.

Comment: А ничего что `while(true)` блокирует `EventHandler`? Я не специалист в Xamarin.Forms, обычно в обработчиках событий такое не разрешается.